# google app engine tools for android Eclipse current instructions not working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I followed the latest instructions on http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt to install ADT and additional packages

Then I followed instructions on https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2 to install Google App Engine Tools for Android (Requires ADT).

I have ADT v23 from the above. However, when I try to install GAE tools for Android V3.5.1 as instructed from the second link above. I got the following error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42) requires 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0' but it could not be found

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of GPE was released today (3.6.0) that fixes this problem. Try the latest GPE.

Comment: Yep. That was fast. Thanks!